# Sum of multiple tables mysql problems

Tags: php, mysql

```
$nstkquty=$db->execute("SELECT (SUM(p.quantity) - SUM(s.quantity) -
                                SUM(o.quantity) - SUM(pr.quantity)) AS totalquty 
                        FROM master_purchase AS p, product_sales AS s,
                             orders_details AS o, purchase_return AS pr 
                        WHERE p.product_code='" . $cod . "' && 
                              s.prd_code='" . $cod . "' && 
                              o.prd_code='" . $cod . "' &&  
                              pr.product_code='" . $cod . "'");
$nwrquty = $nstkquty->fetch_assoc();
$data['avalqty'] = $nwrquty[0] ['SUM(totalquty)']; //$total_stkqty;
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

Here is my code there is no result to display, no errors and no warnings to display. Any one help me to solve this problems.

Comment: Did you even try to use that query in any sql client?

Comment: `echo "SELECT (SUM(p.quantity)-SUM(s.quantity)-SUM(o.quantity)-SUM(pr.quantity)) AS totalquty FROM master_purchase AS p,product_sales AS s,orders_details AS o,purchase_return AS pr where p.product_code='".$cod."' && s.prd_code='".$cod."' && o.prd_code='".$cod."' && pr.product_code='".$cod."'");"` and try it in phpmyadmin and check for errors

Comment: no errors shown it display totalquty = NULL

Answer (score 0):

Not used 
$data['avalqty'] = $nwrquty[0] ['SUM(totalquty)'];

Used like
$data['avalqty'] = $nwrquty[0] ['totalquty'];

Answer (score 0):

Update your query:

```
$nstkquty=$db->execute("SELECT ( sum(if(p.quantity is null, 0, p.quantity)) - sum(if(s.quantity is null, 0, s.quantity)) -
                            sum(if(o.quantity is null, 0, o.quantity)) - sum(if(pr.quantity is null, 0, pr.quantity))) AS totalquty 
                    FROM master_purchase AS p, product_sales AS s,
                         orders_details AS o, purchase_return AS pr 
                    WHERE p.product_code='" . $cod . "' && 
                          s.prd_code='" . $cod . "' && 
                          o.prd_code='" . $cod . "' &&  
                          pr.product_code='" . $cod . "'");
```

Also update this line to:

```
$data['avalqty'] = $nwrquty[0] ['totalquty']; //$total_stkqty;
```

Comment: what is the result?run the query in mysql directly

Comment: The Result is : totalquty NULL

Comment: echo the query in browser & post here

Comment: i want to sum quantity in my 4 tables in a single query, now i am using 4 select query the above query not working properly ..